# Getting the list of Points of Interest

Tags: python, point-of-interest

Can anyone guide me on how to get a list of POI from a particular Location?
I have a list of Latitude and Longitude, I want to retrieve the list of POI around every location using python.

I am a beginner so I don't really know from where to start

Comment: Not enough info...what is POI in your understanding? Do you want to use APIs, some particular maps provider, in what radius, is it supposed to be standalone script or a piece of sth bigger (e.g. a python backend for some web app), etc.

Comment: Extract the restaurants, hotels, Hospitals, Malls... etc within a 500m radius of the given locations, I want to extract them on a word file if it is possible. example: every location with different related POI around

Comment: Welcome! Could you please provide more information in your question? Do you have one list, e.g. `coords = [(30,40), (99,20)]` and then an internet service that you want to query? It is no clear from where you want to retrieve the POI. Please provide detailed information what your source is, how you want to access it, etc. Also please provide a minimal reproducible example and the expected output if possible (please see [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for more detailed information).
We will gladly help as soon as we have enough information to understand your problem :-)

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.